# had we just not found

Tags: tense

Why was that? Was he the sort of “exceptionalist” phenomenon that transcended explanation—or had we just not *found* the events obscured by history, the missing piece of the puzzle that might constitute evidence for an explanation?

Source: Ron Rosenbaum: *Explaining Hitler*, p. viii.

I am thinking about the usage of past perfect ("had we just not found") in the above sentence. I would expect the present perfect – we have not yet found the explanation for the personality of Hitler.

Comment: Rosenbaum writes this in the Preface to the Updated Edition, where he discusses what led him to write the book sixteen years earlier: the past time at which he was asking these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author was talking from a past period of time and looking back to something even further in the past.

In the previous paragraph, he wrote that Hitler "had . . . escaped . . . theories that sought to pin him down."

We can refer to this point in time when people were trying to pin him down with theories (and when he *escaped* such efforts) as an ANCHOR TIME IN THE PAST (anchor time).

The author wonders what had happened before anchor time that explains how or why Hitler escaped a simple or single explanation (of why he was who he was, why he did what he did).

Therefore, the author is talking about something that happened and finished in the past before another past event or moment. This is the main use of the past perfect.